# Cython extension types attributes misunderstanding

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to grant python access for a member inside a cython class. The member type is basic (e.g. `int` or `float`)

As I read in the documentation, you can use [properties](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html?highlight=properties#properties) to give access to the underlying C++ member:

```
cdef class myPythonClass:

   # grant access to myCppMember thanks to myMember
   property myMember:
      def __get__(self):
        return self.thisptr.myCppMember # implicit conversion
      # would somehow be the same logic for __set__ method
```

Now this works.

**However**, as far as I understand, for basic types you can just use [extension types](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html?highlight=readonly#attributes). In this case, you make the member `public` to make it accessible and/or writable. You don't need properties:

```
 cdef class myPythonClass:
    cdef public int myCppMember # direct access to myCppMember
```

But when I use this second option, it does not work. The variable is never updated. Is there something I'm missing or I did not fully understood?

Thanks for you input.

Comment: Can you show an example of it not working like you expect?

Comment: @carmellose you can also use an external `def` function in Cython to extract a `public` attribute, but not a `private` attribute (for the latter you must use a class method, similarly to the `property` approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found the solution, using `property` is the way to go.

A `public` attribute can be accessed outside a class method, while a `private` attributes can only be used by the class methods.

But even `public` attributes defined at the C++ level cannot be accessed from Python. And exposing either a `private` or a `public` attribute using `property` will make it available to Python.